# Setting up a Job Schedule

Tags: azure-batch

1. I currently have a setup that creates a job and then collect some metrics about the tasks in the job. I want to do something similar, but by setting a job schedule instead. In particular, I want to set a job schedule that wakes up at a recurrence interval that I specify, and run the same code that I was running when creating a job. What's the best way to go about doing that?
2. It seems that there is a CloudJobSchedule that I could use to set up my job schedule, but this only lets me create say a job manager task, and specify few properties. How can I run external code on the jobs created by the Job schedule?
3. It could also help to clarify how the CloudJobSchedule works. Specifically, after I commit my job schedule, what would happen programmatically. Does the code just move sequentially and run the rest of the code. In this case, does it make sense to get a reference to the last job created by the job schedule and run code on the job returned?

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll want to create a [CloudJobSchedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.cloudjobschedule?view=azurebatch-7.0.1). You can specify the recurrence in the [Schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.schedule?view=azurebatch-7.0.1).
2. If you only need to run a single task per recurrence, your job manager task can simply be the task you need to run. If you need to run multiple tasks per job recurrence, your job manager needs to have logic to submit tasks to Batch and monitor for completion (if necessary).
3. When you submit a job schedule to Batch, your client side code will continue running. The behavior is no different than if you were submitting a regular job. You can retrieve the last job run via [JobScheduleExecutionInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.jobscheduleexecutioninformation?view=azurebatch-7.0.1) and the [RecentJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.recentjob?view=azurebatch-7.0.1) property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1. The link you provided is for REST API, right? Is there a recommended way using C#? Would it be CloudJobSchedule class 2. My job manager task currently creates all the tasks and monitors for completion, but I was collecting execution metrics outside job manager task 3. How soon is the executionInfo and recentJob property available for use after I commit the job schedule using `await jobSchedule.CommitAsync()`?

Comment: Also, 3. Is my client side code invoked each time a job is created or only the first time that a job schedule is committed?

Comment: 1. Yes, corrected to the C#/.NET SDK. Yes, the recommendation is the same. 3. RecentJob property is available when a job is executed according to the specified Schedule. Your client side code only executes on the client - sorry I don't quite understand what you're asking here.

Comment: @fredpark 3. can I call the RecentJob property after the commit line above or is it only available after a job finishes executing? 3'. I am sorry my question was confusing, I'll try again. So after I commit a job schedule, a job would be created say every 30 min. But after committing the job schedule, you said the client side code continues running, so whatever comes after the commit line will run. My question was, would the code after the commit line run each time a new job is created by the job schedule, or just 1st time as the job schedule would only be running in the background?

Comment: Also, I have been running some tests and the RecentJob property keeps returning null. When does it become non-null?

Comment: RecentJob will return a valid result once a job is scheduled and execution of the job begins.